# SharePoint list: Power Query only returns records Created By me

Tags: list, item-level-permissions, power-query

I have a SharePoint list where I am the owner with **full access and I see all records in the web frontend**. I have enabled **item-level permission** for normal users ("Read, create and edit items that were created by the user" in List Advanced Settings)

I also have an Excel connected to the SharePoint list, reading all data with a **Power Query**. Until last week the query was working fine and returning all records. Suddenly as of today it is **only returning the records created by me**.

When I turn off the item-level permission I can retrieve all records again. However, as I have full access I would expect to get all items even when item-level security is turned on (as is still the case in the web frontend)

Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: I have had the exact same issue. My query has been working fine for the last year and has just started only retrieving my entries as of today. No changes to the list or our SharePoint site in the last week. Could this be a wider SP issue? Please let me know if you find the solution!

Comment: No solution so far. Just as a workaround: I am changing the item-level permission to _Read all items_ then I quickly refresh the query in Excel and reset the item-level permission to _Read items that were created by the user_. Not ideal ... but it works.